# Set a subview as the responder to calls to a parent UIView subclass

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I've got a UIView that I've subclassed to be the main view used throughout my app.  In it, I have two subviews: banner and container.  Banner is basically a place to put an ad or a disclaimer or whatever.  Container is meant to act as the primary view, to which you can add, remove and whatever as if it were the only view.

Right now, I'm just overriding the methods of the parent view and sending the calls to the container view.  I'm wondering if there is an easier way to do this, without having to write out stuff like this for every method:

```
- (void)addSubview:(UIView*)view {
  [container addSubview:view];
}
```

Maybe something that lets you delegate all method calls to the view to a specific subview, rather than responding to the method calls itself.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by the question.

The responder chain is present and passes ui events up through all visible views on screen, by hierarchy. It may be useful to read a little about the responder chain, because by design it passes events from the deepest view to the highest (root) in that order, which is the opposite of the direction you're seeking (if I'm reading this right).

If you need to forward events from a superview to a subview, to respect principles of encapsulation, you should define appropriate actions in your subview's subclass interface, and then then configure your superview to target the actions in that subview/class.

Comment: This is less about responding to UI actions and more about making a subview of the primary view act as if it were the primary view to outside method calls. For instance, when I add my BaseView subclass as the view of a navigation controller, I would like if all the calls to `self.view` methods were instead passed to that specific subview of self.view without having to override all of the methods of UIView.

Comment: You might be over thinking it a little bit. A view controller has an implicit view [self view], but it's not limited to having one view, so in your case you'd instantiate two views in the view controllers loadView - one being your baseView, assigned directly to the view controller's self.view, and then an additional peripheral view, added to the same superview, but not assigned as the view controller's self.view (rather it would be referenced presumably by another property on your VC subclass, i.e. , self.extraView.

Comment: If you're saying add the extra view to the self.view's superview, i.e., `[self.view.superview addSubview:extraView]`, this does not actually seem to work.  Xcode doesn't argue with me or anything, but the view just doesn't show up.  I don't think a view controller is designed to show anything that's not in the primary view...?

Comment: Sorry, re-reading my answer isn't very clear and you're right. Adding a view directly to a superview would also violate rules of encapsulation. But why not just move both your views down one step in the chain? So your application has one root view that contains two subviews: Your banner and main views. If we forget about banner view, any subviews/actions/logic that occur in or below mainView may just as well consider *it* the root, further accessible by mainView.view.

Comment: Basically that's what I'm trying to do here, but without having to rewrite all the calls in my app from `self.view` to `self.mainView`.  So far my overriding of view methods to to just pass the call onto a subview is working fine, but I was just wondering if there was another way to do it, i.e. forward all calls on one view to one of its subviews.